# Foundation font reset and navigation alternatives

Tags: navigation, zurb-foundation, font-size

On recent projects, I'm taking more time to reset and change a lot of CSS properties Foundation framework is providing to fit my needs, but at the same time I'm enjoying some specific scripts Foundation provides like the grid or responsive menu.

I got 2 questions :

1) is there a way to clearly reset or cancel all the font-sizes produced in the Foundation CSS files because I d'like to use a body 67.5% values and different rem size, without having to overwrite a lot of CSS ?

2) if I'm not using a framework this time, do you know a script similar to the Foundation responsive menu with multi-level support and animation, I can't find something great like this one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot customize font size with out having to change lot of css.
here is a link to customize foundation but it dosent include customizing font-size.
do it using sass or have separate classes to your typography.

## [customize foundation Link](http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html#customizeFoundation)

If you want to use other grid systems..have a look at this resources page -[resources](http://bradfrost.github.io/this-is-responsive/resources.html).

lot of frameworks listed in it go thorugh them and choose that fits your needs.